# how to delete a token when cancel is clicked

Tags: php

how can i get a token that a user has requested if he/she clicks cancel NOTE the user doesnt have to input anything if cancel is clicked that particular token is deleted from the d.b and the user is redirected to index.php i really dont know where and how to start so bear with me thanks anyway below is the token.php

```
<?php
error_reporting(0);
session_start();
$token=$_GET['token'];
include("settings.php");
connect();
if(isset ($_POST['submit'])){
$q="select email from tokens where token='".$token."' and used=0";
$r=mysql_query($q);
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($r))
   {
$email=$row['email'];
   }
If ($email!=''){
          $_SESSION['email']=$email;
}
else die("Invalid link or Password already changed  <a href='../index.php'>Click here to go back to the HOME PAGE<a/>");}
$pass=$_POST['password'];
$email=$_SESSION['email'];
if(isset($_POST['password'])&&isset($_SESSION['email']))
{
$q="update registration set password='".md5($pass)."' where email='".$email."'";
$r=mysql_query($q);
if($r)mysql_query("update tokens set used=1 where token='".$token."'");echo "Your password is changed successfully  <a href='../index.php'>Click here to go back to the HOME PAGE<a/>";
if(!$r)echo "An error occurred";
    }
```

and below is the formreset.php

```
<h3><strong>Forgot Password</strong></h3>
      <form name="forgot" method="POST" id="forgot" action="includes/reset.php?token=<?php echo $_GET['token']; ?>">
        <div align="center">
          <table width="372" border="0">
            <tr>
              <td width="181"><p>&nbsp;</p>
              <p><strong>Password</strong></p></td>
              <td width="181"><span id="sprytextfield1"><span id="sprypassword1">
              <label for="password2"></label>
              <br />
            <input type="password" name="password" id="password2" />
                <br />
                <span class="passwordRequiredMsg">Your PASSWORD is need</span></span>
<label for="label"></label>
              </span></td>
</tr>
            <tr>
              <td height="22"><p>&nbsp;
              <p><strong>Confirm Password</strong></p></td>
              <td><span id="spryconfirm2">
              <label for="password"></label>
              <span id="spryconfirm1">
              <label for="password1"></label>
              <br />
              <input type="password" name="password1" id="password1" />
              <br />
              <span class="confirmRequiredMsg">Please re-confirm your PASSWORD</span><span class="confirmInvalidMsg">The PASSWORDS don't match.</span></span></span></td>
</tr>
</table>
</div>
    <div align="center">
      <p>&nbsp;</p>
      <table width="372" border="0">
        <tr>
          <th width="132" scope="row"><input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="submit" /></th>
          <th width="113" scope="row"><a href="includes/cancel.php?token=<?php echo $_GET['token']; ?>">Cancel</a></td></th>
          <th width="113" scope="row"><input type="reset" name="clear" id="clear" value="Clear" /></th>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </div>
    <div align="center">
      <table width="372" border="0">
        <tr> </tr>
        <tr> </tr>
      </table>
    </div>thanks in advance
  </form>
```

so how do i go about this

Comment: Can you make it clearer, if token is posted into a page, then how do you want to cancel it?

Comment: Unrelated to your question: Your script is vulnerable to Cross site scripting, and possibly vulnerable to SQL injection if your server doesn't have Magic quotes on.

Comment: Create a javascript callback that when cancel is clicked calls via ajax  /remove/token/:id ? Puzzled about the question.

Comment: abt the magic quotes i will look into it thanks for now what  i mean is incase a user decides he/she doent want to change the password then they can cancel it

Comment: @Bjoern Rennhak thanks but i need the token to be deleted from the d.b without the user inputing anything as the  token is coming from the d.b

Comment: Btw. md5 for passwords is just plainly wrong. See this writeup for more info. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16564514/create-user-on-mysql-with-md5-password/16564716#16564716

Comment: http://www.danbriant.com/general/creating-php-password-reset-script/

Comment: @Bjoern Rennhak i will look into that for now i need help on this issue

Comment: i already saw that one @Bjoern Rennhak but i alrdy got a working just this small issue

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
$token = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['token']);
mysql_query("DELETE FROM tokens WHERE token='$token'") or die (mysql_error());
header("Location: index.php");
```

Comment: Ahh, it's one of those long random strings that should be hard to guess. Of course.

Comment: :) yeap so what can u suggest please bear with me

Comment: Suggest for what? As long as the token isn't guessable, there's nothing else you need to do.

Comment: I mean if the user wants to cancel

Comment: Doesn't my answer do that?

Comment: nope not doing the trick 1st of all its giving me an undefined index token and second its not getting the token

Comment: I don't understand why that's happening. Didn't you click on a link that has `cancel.php?token=something` in it? That will set `$_GET['token']`.

Comment: Try `var_dump($_GET)`, what do you see?

Comment: i get a null wen that is put

Comment: I have no idea. Even if there are no parameters, it should say `array(0) { }`. There's something wrong with your PHP configuration if it doesn't set `$_GET`.

Comment: wat i also i want the link to expire wat should i do

Comment: What we do in our system is put a timestamp in the table, and run a script every day that deletes all rows whose timestamp is more than a week old.

Comment: I don't see the problem, it's a trivial program to write. If you have trouble getting it to work, ask a new question. SO comments are not for extended discussions. The SQL is simple: `delete from tokens where token_timestamp < now() - interval 1 week`.

Comment: i mean any query if yes where do i put it

Comment: You put it in a script that you run from cron every day. This is really basic system administration stuff.